# Правильное удаление клика с элементов

Tags: javascript, массивы, события, dom

Хотелось бы, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку прошлый клик с переменной 'hi' удалялся. Но почему-то этого не происходит

```js
let li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    let butt = document.getElementById('delete');

    function action(text){
        console.log(text);
    }

    Array.from(li, function (item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function () {
            action('hi');
        });
    });
    
    butt.addEventListener('click', function () {
        Array.from(li, function (item) {
            item.removeEventListener('click', function () {
                action('hi');
            });
            item.addEventListener('click', function () {
                action('bye');
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<button id="delete">Delete first click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что такие конструкции

```
    item.addEventListener('click', function () {
        action('hi');
    });
    ...
    item.removeEventListener('click', function () {
        action('hi');
    });
```

создают новый объект функции-обработчика.

```js
let li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
let butt = document.getElementById('delete');

function action(text) {
  console.log(text);
}

function hi() {
  action('hi');
}

Array.from(li, function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', hi);
});

butt.addEventListener('click', function() {
  Array.from(li, function(item) {
    item.removeEventListener('click', hi);
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
      action('bye');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
<button id="delete">Delete first click</button>
```

Comment: никак не сделать иначе, если в функции очень нужны будут переменные? Это же в этой чисто для примера console.log, а так внутри может быть всё, что угодно

Comment: @Anna Не понял про "переменные в функции". Приведите пример.